# Help with multidimensional arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code to split a string into groups of 3 bytes:

```
str="hello"
ix=0, iy=0
bytes=[]
tby=[]
str.each_byte do |c|
    if iy==3 
        iy=0
        bytes[ix]=[]
        tby.each_index do |i|
            bytes[ix][i]=tby[i]
        end
        ix+=1
    end
    tby[iy]=c
    iy+=1
end
puts bytes
```

I've based it on this example: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/75570

However I'm getting type errors from it. Thanks.

Comment: can't convert Array into Integer.. but the example is almost exactly the same and doesn't get these type errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ix = 0, iy = 0` translates to `ix = [0, (iy = 0)]`, which is why you get a type error.

However there is a less "procedural" way to do what you want to do:

For ruby 1.8.7+:

```
"hello world".each_byte.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [[104, 101, 108], [108, 111, 32], [119, 111, 114], [108, 100]]
```

For ruby 1.8.6:

```
require 'enumerator'
"hello world".enum_for(:each_byte).enum_for(:each_slice, 3).to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the line

```
ix=0, iy=0
```

It sets the value of ix to an array of twice 0, and iy to 0. You should replace it by

```
ix, iy = 0, 0
```